# React-native footer within scrollview

Tags: react-native, view, scrollview, footer

As I wanted to create a footer, I followed the advices saying I had to put a scrollview within a view to make it  right. 
Well, that's almost perfect but could you help me with one detail ? in the red circle of the picture, we can see that my view is visible. I would like to make the top of it disappear. I tried  marginTop: 0 and paddingTop: 0, but it didn't work. 
Thanks for any help !

My code for this page :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Image, View, ScrollView, Text } from "react-native";
import Button from "react-native-flat-button";
import styles from "../../assets/Styles";
import Footer from "../../Components/Footer/Footer";
import { Header } from "react-native-elements";
import MenuButton from "../../Drawer/MenuButton";

export default class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.footer}>
      <Header
        rightComponent={<MenuButton navigation={this.props.navigation} />}
        centerComponent={{ text: 'Bienvenue au Gavroche',  style: {fontFamily: "Parisienne", fontSize: 24, color: '#fff' } }}
        containerStyle={{
          backgroundColor: "#013243",
          justifyContent: "space-around"
        }}
        statusBarProps={{ barStyle: "light-content" }}
      />
        <ScrollView style={styles.containerScroll}>
          <View style={styles.container}>
            <Image
              style={styles.welcomeimg}
              source={require("../../assets/Images/facade.png")}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={styles.buttonView}>
            <Button
              type="custom"
              activeOpacity={0.5}
              containerStyle={styles.buttonContainer}
              contentStyle={styles.buttonWelcome}
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Restaurant")}
            >
              Restaurant
            </Button>
            <Button
              type="custom"
              activeOpacity={0.5}
              containerStyle={styles.buttonContainer}
              contentStyle={styles.buttonWelcome}
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Carte")}
            >
              Carte
            </Button>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.buttonView}>
            <Button
              type="custom"
              activeOpacity={0.5}
              containerStyle={styles.buttonContainer}
              contentStyle={styles.buttonWelcome}
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Vins")}
            >
              Vins
            </Button>
            <Button
              type="custom"
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Actus")}
              activeOpacity={0.5}
              containerStyle={styles.buttonContainer}
              contentStyle={styles.buttonWelcome}
            >
              Actus
            </Button>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.buttonView}>
            <Button
              type="custom"
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Reservation")}
              activeOpacity={0.5}
              containerStyle={styles.buttonContainer}
              contentStyle={styles.buttonWelcome}
            >
              Réservation
            </Button>
            <Button
              type="custom"
              onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Acces")}
              containerStyle={styles.buttonContainer}
              contentStyle={styles.buttonWelcome}
            >
              Accès
            </Button>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
        <Footer />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: View sticking out]

Comment: can you share the expo snack of this page? ill check there and fix it

Comment: Sorry for the delay... https://snack.expo.io/@charlotter/5e018b

Comment: the expo snack is not workin, can you just share the only single screen in expo snack where i need to check and makeit working in expo please

Comment: It seems to work with this snack (I removed the image) https://snack.expo.io/@charlotter/gavroche
Tell me if you can't see.

Comment: its not working

Comment: Oh ?  it works on my phone ... i'll check this out...